# How to create a zeros array in Julia?

Tags: julia

In many Machine Learning use cases, you need to create an array filled with zeros, with specific dimensions. In Python, I would use `np.zeros((2, 1))` to create a 2x1 array. What is the analog version of this in Julia?

Comment: Mighty similar to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872856/how-to-create-a-ones-array-in-julia. Don't thrash the system.

Comment: `zeros(Int8, 2, 3)` outputs a 2×3 Matrix{Int8}. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.zeros

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Comment: Then copy-paste the whole julia doc.

Comment: That wasn't in response to your comment, sorry Eric, just adding that there for reference! Thanks for the suggestion above ^

Comment: Feel free to add an answer or edit mine below to add additional content you think is relevant.

Comment: I agree that `ones` and `zeros` should be just 1 post instead of being scattered across 2. In fact, why not a master post of ways to make an `Array{T,N}` of dummy values. You can even talk about the mutable object `fill` trap.

Comment: That is a fair point of view. IMO, they warrant different posts, for example, I was inspired to post this as I was working through an unrelated ML project where I needed to create an empty array of ones and zeros. The search results for Tensorflow was exactly what I needed when searching "how to create a zeros array in python", etc. Thus I posted this. Making the post generic requires the user to really search for the "right thing" which I myself would not have done since I am a novice in this field.

Comment: I do think there would be value in a more general version of this, I just also think the explicit one is quite helpful as well.

Comment: Yes, an overly general title would evade common search terms, but in this specific case, "how to create a zeros or ones array for a type" would be plenty searchable, imo.

Comment: yes, fair point!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Julia, many of the operations from packages like `numpy` are built into the standard library. In the case of creating an array of zeros, you can do the following:

```
julia> zeros(2, 1)
2×1 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
```

You can read more about the `zeros` function in the [Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.zeros).